# Showing Ad Banners below Tabs in Meteoric

Tags: meteor, meteoric

Question on Meteoric tabs.

Im having a problem displaying my admob ads below the Tabs.

Is there a way to move up the tabs bar on the bottom? I'm guessing this can be done in with custom CSS overriding current tabs values.  Does anyone know how to do this?